# How to display raw table in .Net Core 2.1 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, datatable

Very new to Web Apps. Have experience with WPF.
I need to display a table from an Oracle Database. I have been able to query the table and retrieve some info. Here is the code to do that:

```
public DataTable Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        string constr = "MyConnString";
        string cmdstr = "select *  from table where udc_id = '1111111'";
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmdstr, constr);
        OracleCommandBuilder builder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }
```

[Note: I utilized the auto-generated Code by visual Studio. In this case the Contact() method.]
The data retrieved is a long string and not in a table format. Output from above method: 
[{"id":999,"devicE_CLASS_ID":743,"udC_ID":"1111111","make":null}]
My question is how can I convert the data into a table? My guess is that I will have to create a Modal class then connect my View to the Modal via the Controllers. However my app needs to simply display raw table contents from various databases some of them are in DB2, MS Access and SQL Server. I do not want to go the Modal creation route as that would be pretty time consuming.
I have worked on something very similar in WPF and in it I simple query the database, get the result in a DataTable and display it using DataGridView. Looking for something similar with Web Apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't.

There is no control to display a `DataTabe` directly in HTML. So neither do ASP.NET Core. The only way is to write a `<table>` in HTML and build it by your own C#.

```html
<table>
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in yourCollection)
    {
      ...Render it here...
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But, Visual Studio can help you to make this step easier. Please follow the document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/displaying-a-table-of-database-data-cs

Finally, Visual Studio will generate the modal and view code automatically so you don't have to write model by yourself.

Comment: That is correct. Guess more hard work for me. Thanks for your answer.